# Why don't jQuery/JavaScript (classname or id).value.length work when validating username?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", mouseOver1);

function mouseOver1(){

   document.getElementById("button1").style.color = "red";

}


document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", mouseOver); 


    function mouseOver(){ 

      document.getElementById("button2").style.color = "purple";
   }



$("#button1").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
}); 

$("#button2").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
}); 
 

 $('#button1').on('click', function () {
   var error = 0; 
   var usernameError = document.getElementById("username_error1");
   var passwordError = document.getElementById("password_error2");

   if ($(".existingUsername").get(0).value != "S0104675") {
   usernameError.innerHTML = "Please enter an existing valid username";
    error = 1; 
    } else {
    usernameError.innerHTML = '';
   } 
   if ($(".existingPassword").get(0).value != "honor433") {
    passwordError.innerHTML = "Please enter an existing valid password";
     error = 1;

   } else {
    passwordError.innerHTML = '';
  }
  if(error == 0)
  {  
     $("#para1").animate({ left: "-100%" });
     $(".username-label").animate({ left: "-105%" });
     $(".existingUsername").animate({ left: "-105%" });
     $(".password-label").animate({ left: "-105%" });
     $(".existingPassword").animate({ left: "-105%" });
     $("#button1").animate({ left: "-105%" });
  }

});

$('#button2').on('click', function () {

var newUsernameError = $("#New_Username_error").html('');
var newPasswordError = $("#New_Password_error").html('');
var newEmailAddressError = $("#New_Email_error").html('');
var newRepeatEmailAddressError = $("#Repeat_Email_error").html('');

// just to make the later conditions easier to read, let's grab all the values into vars:
var newUsername = $('.newUsername').val();
var newPassword = $('.newPassword').val();
var newEmail = $('.newEmail').val();
var repeatEmail = $('.repeatEmail').val();

var errorsFound = false; 

if (newUsername === "") {
  errorsFound = true;
  newUsernameError.html("The username must not be empty.");
} else if (newUsername.length < 6) {
  errorsFound = true;
  newUsernameError.html("The username must be at least 6 characters.");
}

if (newPassword.length < 6) {
  errorsFound = true;
  newPasswordError.html("The password must be at least 6 characters.");
}

if (newEmail === "") {
  errorsFound = true;
  newEmailAddressError.html("The email must not be left empty.");
} else if (!/@/.test(newEmail)) {
  errorsFound = true;
  newEmailAddressError.html("The email must contain an @ symbol.");
}

if (repeatEmail !== newEmail) {
  errorsFound = true;
  newRepeatEmailAddressError.html("This repeat email doesn't equal to the first one entered.");
}

});
```

```css
.intro h1 {
  font-family: 'Cambria';
  font-size: 16pt;
  font: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.intro p {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font: italic;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 0px 690px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#para1 {
  padding: 0px 1050px 0px 20px;
  position: relative; 
}

#para2 {
  padding: 0px 1099px 0px 20px;
  position: relative; 
}

.username-label,
.password-label {
 margin: 10px 0px 0px 350px;
 position: relative; 
 top: -70px; 
}

.existingUsername, 
.existingPassword, 
#username_error1, 
#password_error2
{
    top: -70px; 
     position: relative;       
}

#button1{ 
     background-color: #add8e6;
     margin-left: 425px; 
     position: relative; 
     top: -70px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; 
}

#button2{
  background-color: #add8e6;
  margin-left: -500px; 
  position: relative; 
  top: -30px; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; 

}


.Username-label1, 
.Password-label2,           
.Email-label3, 
.Repeat-Email-label4 
{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 330px;
  position: relative; 
  top: -70px; 
}
.newUsername, 
.newPassword, 
.newEmail, 
.repeatEmail{
  position: relative;
   top: -70px;
  margin-left: 40px; 

} 

span{

 color: red; 
 margin-left: 300px;
 position: relative; 
 top: -60px; 
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Project</title>

</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="intro">

    <h1>Welcome to Cuyahoga Community College Student Services Online</h1>

    <p>Cuyahoga Community College recognizes students' rights to access personal and academic records in accordance with the Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act of 1974 (FERPA) as amended by Public Law 93-568.</p>
  </div>
  <br/>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="row top">
      <p id="para1">Already have an account with us? Returning users may log in by entering their site username and password. </p>
      <div class="login">
        <label class="username-label" for="existingUsername">Username</label> 
         <input class="existingUsername" type="text" /><br><span id="username_error1"></span><br>


        <label class="password-label" for="existingPassword">Password</label>
        <input class="existingPassword" type="password"/><br><span id="password_error2"></span><br>
        <button id="button1">Log in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row bottom">
      <p id="para2">New users, please create a new account by providing us with some basic information.</p>

      <div class= "new_customers_info">

        <label class="Username-label1" for="newUsername">Username</label>
        <input class="newUsername" type="text"/><br><span id="New_Username_error"></span><br>

        <label class="Password-label2" for="newPassword">Password</label>
        <input class="newPassword" type="password"/><br><span id="New_Password_error"></span><br>

        <label class="Email-label3" for="newEmail">Email Address</label>
         <input class="newEmail" type="email"/><br><span id="New_Email_error"></span><br>

        <label class="Repeat-Email-label4" for="repeatEmail">Repeat Email Address</label>
         <input class="repeatEmail" type="email"/><span id="NewReenter_Email_error"></span>

        <button id="button2">Create Account</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <br/>
  <footer>Cuyahoga Community College</footer>
  <footer>700 Carnegie Avenue, Cleveland, Ohio, 44115</footer>
</div>
    <script src="Home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working on validating (the lower part) text boxes, and I have encountered a problem when trying to validate username text box. For example, with the `value.length` (which I changed to length) in my first if condition.

When I click on the 'Create an account' button, it doesn't do anything (which I know that it shouldn't do anything now only if the username is at least 6 characters, but when I do className or Id.length it works) but for some reason it displays the error message, even though I have the correct length of words or more inside the text box.

Here is my code.

Comment: To help us help you better, please remove all the example code that does not directly relate to the piece you're having trouble with. Try and make sure your example is Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: also avoid combining pure js with jquery

Comment: why are you mixing jquery and DOM? Pick one and stick with it

Comment: @ epascarello How do I get my span id's to display one of two different messages? For example, if the username doesn't have enough length (I already have this one) or if the username already exists? Do I need to create two different span for the input texboxes. I have one for each input texbox now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$(".newUsername").length` use `$(".newUsername").val().length`.

**EDIT:**

I'd like to follow @Stephen P 's kind suggestions. `$(".newUsername")` returns an array of all the elements that satisfies the `.newUsername` selector, or all the elements that has the `newUsername` class. `$(".newUsername").length` returns the length of the array, or in this case the number of elements that has the class.

However, `$(".newUsername").val()` gets the value of the input, which is a string. `$(".newUsername").val().length` returns the length of the string, which is the value you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: If you feel my answer is helping you, please accept it.

Comment: This would be a more useful answer if you explained the difference between the two lengths; why the second works and the first doesn't. What exactly does `$(".someClassName")` actually return? What does the `.length` of that indicate?